# Is move by lvalue broken/unfinished in msvc2010?

Tags: visual-c++, c++11

I dont know why this code doesnt work. this_ is shown as 0xcccccccc and v is no longer 4. Why?

Note: I am trying to use the lvalue/move semantics.

```
struct AA{
    void*this_;
    int v;
    AA() {v=4;this_=this; }
    AA(AA&a){this_=this; }
    AA(AA&&a){
        this_=a.this_;
        v = a.v;
    }
};
void movetest(AA s) {}
void movetest(AA& s) {}
//void movetest(AA&& s) {}
AA&& movetest() { return AA(); }
void MyTestCode2(){
    AA c = movetest();
    printf("wron value. 4 !='%d'\n", c.v);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's returning a reference to a local.  It should be

```
AA movetest() { return AA(); }
```

This code requires either a move or copy constructor to exist, but MSVC will use the return-value-optimization and not actually call either.  In general, you should design your objects as if moves or copies happen outside your control--just maintain consistent state of your object, don't rely on their side-effects.

VC2010 is correctly preferring move to copy, for example on a debug build

AA movetest() 
{
    AA a;
    return a; 
}

calls the AA(AA&&) constructor not the AA(AA&) one.

Comment: With that solution, AA&& is never called. I tested by writing `a=a.v+1` so my log should print 5. But anyways, how am i to use lvalue in functions?

Comment: edited my answer to show forcing the move construction with std::move

Comment: From what i see i need to cast AA&& or use std::move(which is a cast but after removing references). return AA() seems to be optimize (this is debug mode). It doesnt call the copy constructor. It will if i write AA a; retun a;. So... i dont understand why (at least with visual c++) AA&& isnt an error/warning if the object will go out of scope before anything can be done with it. +1 and accepeted

Comment: Is the use of `std::move` in `return std::move(AA())` not superfluous?  The whole point of `std::move` is in effect to enable an "lvalue-to-rvalue" conversion, but here you already have an rvalue.

Comment: It turns a perfectly good RVO construct-in-place into a move-construction.  I'll edit my comment to be less misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Extra info:  This is an answer instead of a comment only because of formatting concerns.

A warning would be nice, but is not required by the language.  Try returning a local lvalue by AA& and see if you get a warning.

clang++ gives the following warning for your code:

```
test.cpp:14:26: warning: returning reference to local temporary object
AA&& movetest() { return AA(); }
                         ^~~~
```